# Spotify App Dead

Tags: spotify

As others have posted, I'm having an issue with my Spotify app (in development) dying after the Spotify update. I can no longer access it as it throws a metadataFailed error. I've tried accessing using the new method "spotify:app:application-identifier-in-manifest" and it doesn't work. I've set both the BundleIdentifier and BundleVersion in the manifest.

Also, I've tried the app on several different computers with several different developer accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, you need to set the `BundleIdentifier` and `BundleVersion` keys, restart Spotify then load it with your identifier. So, if you set your `BundleIdentifier` to `awesome-app`, you'd load it with `spotify:app:awesome-app`.

Comment: Again, I have done exactly this and am still running into the issue.

Comment: In that case you have an invalid manifest. Double-check your JSON syntax, make sure there aren't any BOMs at the beginning of the file (they trip up the parser).

Comment: Here's a copy of my manifest. It validates as valid JSON.


{
 "AcceptedLinkTypes":[
  "album",
  "track"
 ],
 "AppDescription": "description here",
 "AppIcon": {
  "18x18": "images/icon18.png",
  "64x64": "images/icon64.png",
  "128x128": "images/icon128.png"
 },
 "AppName": {
  "en": "SongBop"
 },
 "BundleCopyright": "All rights reserved",
 "BundleIndentifier": "songbop",
 "BundleType": "Application",
 "BundleVersion": "1.0",
 "RequiredInterface": "1",
 "SupportedLanguages": [
  "en"
 ],
 "VendorIdentifier": "com.songbop"
}

Comment: Maybe have a look at my Manifest file. Hope it will help you! [Manifest.json](https://github.com/mickvandijk/Subscribey/blob/master/manifest.json)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mick. I was able to modify your file and get it working. There must be a nonprinting character or something in mine. :)

Comment: Just been playing around with this myself, for anyone else who has a similar issue, I didn't have the "tutorial.css" file in my app and this missing file was causing it all to appear blank

Answer (score 1):

I happened upon a similar issue today, and it was down to my manifest.json not parsing correctly.

Make sure you run your json file through a lint http://jsonlint.com/ before committing and debugging. Saved me a whole bunch of time yak shaving.