# Spotify cannot find my app

Tags: spotify

I created my first Spotify app. I put my manifest.json, cafeplaylist.js, and index.html in users/tati/documents/cafeplaylist on my Windows machine. From Spotify (which knows I am a developer, proven by the fact I have a Develop tab), I type spotify:app:cafeplaylist. It cannot find my app!

I also tried this from my Mac, creating tatianabecker/Spotify/cafeplaylist with the same files. It also cannot find my app!

These 3 files can be found in the main file of https://github.com/realoptimal/socialmix

Bummed, as I can't even get going writing my first app if it can't be found. Someone suggested it is because I don't have Premium. Is that is, or something else?

Thanks,

Tatiana

PS I see others have asked similar questions, but their problems were cleared up by putting the files in the right folder... mine persists.

Answer (score 0):

Your github link isnt working, but maybe you should check this question out: [Spotify App Dead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443734/spotify-app-dead)

You probably dont have a BundleIdentifier and a BundleVersion added to your Manifest file.
Check out my [Manifest.json](https://github.com/mickvandijk/Subscribey/blob/master/manifest.json) file, for a correct view!

Hope this helped you out ;)

Comment: A bit more detail on bundle loading here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416228/spotify-apps-dead-after-update

Comment: Thanks Mick. I took your advice and updated the manifest.json. However, it still can't find it. Code is here: https://github.com/tatiana317/socialmix   . Sorry if these are basic questions - I'm an HTML/CSS programmer trying to branch out.

Comment: How are you trying to reach your app? The correct way (with your manifest) should be "spotify:app:cafeplaylist"

Comment: Hi Mick, that is what I tried... But it is still not found. Do I need premium?

Comment: It says: metadata Failed / URI: spotify:app:cafeplaylist / Error: appNotFound

Comment: Any Spotify employees out there that can help? This is a blocking issue!

Comment: Spotify needs to have HTML5 (if i'm correct).. You don't specify your html file with HTML5. And you don't include the .js file in your .html file!